# How do Ilist tables based on column name in sybase?

Tags: sybase

How do I list all the tables in a database that contain a column with a given name?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you want a list of columns in a table, or are you looking for all tables that contain a column, or something else?

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
select distinct object_name(id)
from syscolumns
where name = 'my_column_name'
order by object_name(id)
```

or this way:

```
select distinct so.name
from syscolumns sc
  , sysobjects so
where sc.id = so.id
and   sc.name = 'my_column_name'
order by so.name
```

is that what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use sp_columns stored procedure.

```
sp_columns @column_name = '%column_name%'
```

More info here: [SyBooks Online (Getting Help On Database Objects)](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X20276.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The below query can be used to get column_name with table_name as well.

This will help the user identify the table to which the column_name belongs.

```
select distinct tbl_col.name as Field_name,tbl_object.name as Table_name
from syscolumns tbl_col
  , sysobjects tbl_object
where tbl_col.id = tbl_object.id
order by tbl_object.name
```

Comment: Priceless. Thank you.

Comment: priceless indeed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sp_columns @column_name = '%column_name%'
```